# gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds not updating

Tags: c#, time, spritefont

I just found something that caught my interest. See, I usually do my "timers" with an `int Time = Duration;` and in my update it would go `Time -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.MilliSeconds;`. However, I just tried to do it with `gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds` instead, since I thought it would be more performance-friendly. But now it isn't updating at all!

My code is basically:

Declaring variables:
`int Time = 120;` `SpriteFont spriteFont1;`

Updating: `Time -= gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds;`

Drawing a string to tell me the time: `spriteBatch.Draw(Time, Position, Color.White)`

Somehow, the string only tells me that the time is decreasing when I'm doing it with MilliSeconds, not Seconds. Why?

Comment: Isn't ElapsedGameTime the time elapsed between every update? I could be wrong, but if it's the time between each update, and each update take less than a second, it will always be zero because it resets every time.

Comment: Use `Total*` like `TotalSeconds`, instead of `Seconds`

Comment: @Diamondo25 TotalSeconds would not work for his countdown timer. It would do -1 second, then -2, -3, etc.
And by the way OP, Seconds is not more "performance-friendly" than milliseconds. Well maybe if you have a million calls you could save a few micro-seconds (Don't know exactly how it works internally), but there's no way it will be the bottleneck of your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Seconds` is the amount of time since the last update. Since it updates very fast the time between updates are smaller than seconds. Seconds gets returned as an `int` so you will always get 0.

Comment: Thanks, was already said in the comments, but this is the only physical answer. Also, if I wanted it to be the actual time, not the time between frames, how would it be done?

Comment: Either use `TotalGameTime` or just add the milliseconds to a variable. By storing the time in a variable, you will be able to 'reset' the timer.